# Add gutters between columns in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to add gutters between my columns in Bootstrap 5. I followed the documentation as to how to implement it but for some reason I cannot add gutters between my columns.

I'm using `g-3` to add gutters to my row and per the documentation this should add gutters in between my rows and columns. I've tried using `gap-3` but then it moves the 3rd column to the next row.

What am I missing here?

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-lg-3 text-center g-3">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1>Services</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-white border rounded p-3">
                <img class="rounded-circle" src="#" alt="#">
                <h4>Title Here</h4>
                <p>Some more info here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-white border rounded p-3">
                <img src="#" alt="#">
                <h4>Title Here</h4>
                <p>Some more info here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-white border rounded p-3">
                <img src="#" alt="#">
                <h4>Title Here</h4>
                <p>Some more info here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-white border rounded p-3">
                <img src="#" alt="#">
                <h4>Title Here</h4>
                <p>Some more info here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-white border rounded p-3">
                <img src="#" alt="#">
                <h4>Title Here</h4>
                <p>Some more info here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col bg-white border rounded p-3">
                <img src="#" alt="alt text">
                <h4>Title Here</h4>
                <p>Some more info here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this issue was that I had to create another div inside my `col` div which should have the classes of `bg-white border rounded p-3` and it should not be inside the `col` div.

check the code down below.

#### I replaced this

```
<div class="col bg-white border rounded p-3">
     <img class="rounded-circle" src="#" alt="#">
     <h4>Title Here</h4>
     <p>Some more info here</p>
</div>
```

#### With this

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="bg-white border p-3">
         <img src="#" alt="alt text">
         <h4>Title Here</h4>
          <p>Some more info here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first column is taking the entire row - all 12 columns.  If you change the first column to `<div class=“col”>` does it give what you want?

Comment: hi @Michael, I posted the correction down. It had something to do with the fact that I put styles on the ```col``` div and it should have been on a div inside the div with the ```col``` class. Thank!